# loop overwrites and only display the last value

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I have loop were I display 3 subsites, the count gets 3 when it finish and it display the last value

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Get the URI decoded URLs.
    hostweburl =
        decodeURIComponent(
            getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl")
    );
    appweburl =
        decodeURIComponent(
            getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl")
    );

    // resources are in URLs in the form:
    // web_url/_layouts/15/resource
    var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";

    // Load the js files and continue to the successHandler
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", execCrossDomainRequest);
});

// Function to prepare and issue the request to get
//  SharePoint data
function execCrossDomainRequest() {
    // executor: The RequestExecutor object
    // Initialize the RequestExecutor with the app web URL.
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    executor.executeAsync(
        {          
            url:appweburl +"/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/webs?@target='" +hostweburl + "'",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: successHandler,
            error: errorHandler
        }
    );
}

function successHandler(data) {
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
    var results = jsonObject.d.results;
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("Error").innerHTML = results[i].Title;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change below code

```
function successHandler(data) {
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
    var results = jsonObject.d.results;
    var result = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        result = result + results[i].Title + ' ';  
    }
    document.getElementById("Error").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Comment: Alright but then it also displays my site collection title i only wont to display the subsites titles?

Comment: Its the root site. Every sitecollection has a default root site. If you are not using it then delete the root site.

Comment: Yes i know that its the root site but i only want subsites, how could i delete it?

Comment: you can't have subsites without a root site collection, it is not possible to delete the root site, if you do that you delete everything in the collection

Comment: You can put an if condition and skip that result in the for loop.

Comment: alright so how should i do then to only display subsites?

Comment: @Martin is the root site title appearing as the first entry? Then modify the loop as `for(var i=1..`